# Why q is used in this example?

Tags: c

In a ["Compliant Solution" code example](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP02-C.+Be+aware+of+the+short-circuit+behavior+of+the+logical+AND+and+OR+operators;jsessionid=067A917B527A60A0485530A943C1D35A), the variable `q` is used.

However, I am not sure why `q` should be used in this case.

```
char *p = /* Initialize; may or may not be NULL */
char *q = NULL;
if (p == NULL) {
  q = (char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);
  p = q;
}
if (p == NULL) {
  /* Handle malloc() error */
  return;
}

/* Perform some computation based on p */
free(q);
q = NULL;
```

Instead, does the following code behave same as the above code?

```
char *p = /* Initialize; may or may not be NULL */
if (p == NULL) {
  p = (char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);
}
if (p == NULL) {
  /* Handle malloc() error */
  return;
}

/* Perform some computation based on p */
```

Comment: The problem with the second example is that if `p` has been obtained by `malloc` you don't know to `free` it.

Comment: @ Whymarrh: Thank you for editing the post for better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the link you provided, you can read this text:

> In this compliant solution, a second pointer, `q`, is used to indicate whether `malloc()` is called; if not, `q` remains set to `NULL`. Passing `NULL` to `free()` is guaranteed to safely do nothing.

So, the purpose of `q` is to allow your code to determine whether `malloc()` was called.

If `p` is non-`NULL`, then `malloc()` is not called, and `q` is `NULL`.  If `p` was `NULL`, then `malloc()` is called, and `q` is non-`NULL`.

Personally I think this is a weird example, almost obfuscated.  Any slight gain in performance this might have over the straightforward code is not worth the weirdness.

I would write:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

char *p = /* Initialize; may or may not be NULL */
bool malloc_was_called = false;
if (p == NULL) {
  p = (char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);
  malloc_was_called = true;
}
if (p == NULL) {
  /* Handle malloc() error */
  return;
}

/* Perform some computation based on p */
if (malloc_was_called) {
    free(p);
    p = NULL;
}
```

EDIT: It wasn't immediately clear to me, but the purpose of the use of `q` was to free the memory *but only if the function allocated it*.  If `p` is pointing to something, we don't free it; but if we allocated the memory, we do free it.  It was tricky before, but my rewrite makes it more clear IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code you wrote shows more clear intent of the code. I like this better than the original one.

Comment: By the way, as dasblinkenlight wrote, if p is modified (e.g. p++), the free(p) may be changed somehow so that the address malloc_ed is used instead.

Comment: Right, but the above code is a clear way to write what the example was actually trying to show.  The example does not assume that the code modifies `p`, the code just wants to free any memory it allocated itself while not freeing memory that was passed to it.

Comment: @ steveha: I agree to you. The original code does not show whether the p is changed or not in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

Your code would be equivalent only if your guarantee that `p` is not modified.

The reason the `q` is there is to let you clean up the results of `malloc`-ing the memory, without requiring that `p` remains unchanged. Since `q` stores the pointer that you have obtained from `malloc`, the block of code labeled "Perform some computation based on `p`" is allowed to modify `p` - for example, increment it in a loop. The value of `q` would continue pointing to `malloc`-ed block, letting you `free` memory that your code has allocated.

Comment: I like your comment; if the code needs to modify `p` then stashing a copy of the pointer as `q` would make sense.  But I now believe the purpose of that code fragment is to clean up after the `malloc()` in the code, but not touch the pointer `p` if it was already set.  If we didn't allocate the memory we didn't free it.  The explanation was far too terse and it was hard to figure out the point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is one I did not recognize.